# Should I get device ID for Admob when i publish my add

Tags: android, device

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
addTestDevice("HASH_DEVICE_ID")
build();
```

I just use my device ID or How can i remove test mode and use the Correct mode

-How can I change it ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to remove this

`addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) addTestDevice("HASH_DEVICE_ID");`

It has been provided in such a way that only the emulator and your own devices will get test ads. For Example I use my apps even after releasing them and i always keep this code included. I download app on my devices again from play store and use them. It shows test ads only on my device (and the devices whose Device ID I have included). So all other users in the world get Real ad impressions.

Comment: Can you confirm? Is it safe to keep the `addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) addTestDevice("HASH_DEVICE_ID");` in a production app ? Since the `DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR` is a test device will the app work on other people's emulated environments ?

Comment: Yes it is completely safe. I am telling you from experience. i have kept it included in all of my 14 apps. Just so you know, that HASH_DEVICE_ID is actually Device id shown in Logcat when you first time run your app on it. Copy and paste that instead of HASH_DEVICE_ID.

Comment: what if m not using EMULATOR for testing purpose. Still I need to add this line 
addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome,

You will put the Device ID of the AVD emulator where you want to test if Admob works, I have an app using Admob with the Device ID of my emulator test mode and it works fine on real devices. It doesn't show the test banner. But if you want to quit it then your code will look like this:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

Comment: remove this addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            addTestDevice("HASH_DEVICE_ID")  ???

Comment: Yes, delete it if you want to. What those two methods do is to let Admob knows in what emulator you want the test banner ads to appear. You don't have to delete them because the ID is unique in every device. You only will see the test banner in your Android emulator.

Comment: So i don't need to  care it? If ADmob can be displayed on the my phone, can i publish to play stroe??

Comment: Yes, you don't need to care about it. and yeah, after you finish your app, you have to export your signed .apk file and upload it to google play with your Google developer account.